# JanusGraph 0.4.0 throws error when connecting via WebSocket

Tags: javascript, janusgraph

I have a React app that connects to Janusgraph over a websocket connection.  This worked well in version JanusGraph 0.3.1.  I installed version 0.4.0 and it works with the gremlin console, but when trying to connect from javascript websocket with the following simplified sample websocket call:

```
const WebSocketAsPromised = require('websocket-as-promised');

getGraphNames = () => {
    let gremlin_query = 'ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames();';
    this.run_websocket_request(gremlin_query)
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          console.log('GetGraphIds: ', response);
        }
      });
}

run_websocket_request(gremlin_query, reqid = null, close = false) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  var wsstring = 'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin';
  const wsp = new WebSocketAsPromised(wsstring, {
    packMessage: data => JSON.stringify(data),
    unpackMessage: message => JSON.parse(message)
  });
  wsp.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    var response = JSON.parse(message);
    //console.log('run_websocket_request: ', response.result.data);
    if (!reqid) {
      wsp.close();
      return resolve(response.result.data);
    } else {
      if (close) {
        wsp.close();
      }
      return resolve(response.result.data);
    }
  });

  wsp.onClose.addListener(event => console.log('Connections closed: ', event.reason));

  wsp.open()
    .then(() => wsp.sendPacked(msg))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error: ', err);
      reject(err);
    }
    );
});
}
```

I get no response and I get the following error in the server logs:

```
6645484 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN  io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0 cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.MessageTextSerializer
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerProtocolHandler$1.channelRead(WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.java:204)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsAndHttpChannelizerHandler.channelRead(WsAndHttpChannelizerHandler.java:76)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:582)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0 cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.MessageTextSerializer
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinTextRequestDecoder.decode(WsGremlinTextRequestDecoder.java:55)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinTextRequestDecoder.decode(WsGremlinTextRequestDecoder.java:41)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    ... 40 more
```

I also tried using Graphexp and get the same results.

I don't get any results back from the websocket call in the browser console or the network tab.

Comment: This sounds like a bug (and a regression from 0.3.1). Can you share a small sample code to reproduce this issue, which works in 0.3.1 and fails in 0.4.0, and [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues), please?

Comment: Thanks Misha!  I updated the post and added some sample code that is a pared down version of on the the sample calls.